# Karaf Jetty performance issue

Tags: performance, jetty, osgi, equinox, apache-karaf

I'm using Apache Karaf 2.3.3 with Jetty 9.0.7 bundles installed. Jetty is hosting a Spring-MVC based application which is a RESTFul web service.

When running a benchmark using Karaf + Jetty, on a specific hardware setup I'm getting speed of 40k HTTP operations per second. If I use standalone Jetty (the same version) - it is over 60k HTTP operations per second.

I have default configuration of both Jetty servers, and I can't see any differences. In both cases I set -Xmx to 6G, but tried with various settings. JRE is 1.7.0_45.

CPU and memory consumption reported by the operating system (Ubuntu) is similar in both cases.

Karaf is configured to use Equinox under the covers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using plain Jetty or are you using Pax Web with Jetty 9.x (most likely Pax Web 4)

Comment: @AchimNierbeck No Pax Web, just plain Jetty.

Comment: to bad would have been interesting to see if Pax Web is better/worse ;)